# Telephony cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, broadcastreceiver, telephony

I used this code in BroadcastReceiver but here Telephony cannot be resolved. how can I use Telephony here in BroadcastReceiver? I think that it is because of using it in BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class SmsFilter extends BroadcastReceiver {
 SharedPreferences preferences = null ;
    Context context;
    static ContentResolver ctx;
  String text;


@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {


    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= 4.0){

        Log.i("LOG", "this is: "+Build.VERSION.RELEASE);    
         final String myPackageName = context.getPackageName();
         if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).equals(myPackageName)) {
             // App is not default.
             // Show the "not currently set as the default SMS app" interface
             View viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.not_default_app);
             viewGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             // Set up a button that allows the user to change the default SMS app
             Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_default_app);
             button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent intent =
                             new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                     intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, 
                             myPackageName);
                     context.startActivity(intent);
                 }
             });
         } else {
             // App is the default.
             // Hide the "not currently set as the default SMS app" interface
             View viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.not_default_app);
             viewGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }





            }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this)` you need `Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context)`. In your case `this` refers to the `BroadcastReceiver`, and the method expects a `context` argument.